# What's the meaning for 2>&1 from docker compose cli command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Just saw some command like

`docker-compose -f $COMPOSE_FILE up -d 2>&1`

Just wondering what's `2>&1` means? I did not find it from https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/

Thanks.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99263/what-does-21-in-this-command-mean

Comment: This is useful when piping output to another command, e.g. `| more`. Otherwise the stderr output would be displayed directly to the terminal instead of being piped. By merging the output, you see the errors together with the stdout that may be related to the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command redirects error output `stderr` from every service defined in `$COMPOSE_FILE` and started to standard output (no error).

So, due to you are getting services up in background (option detach `-d`), with your command you'll see errors in containers deployment. 
Furthermore, it lets you send `stdout` + `stderr` logs to a file if you add `> log.txt` at your command.